# JBoss AS 7 Hibernate class autodetection not working (not a managed type)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, migration, weblogic

I have a Spring + Hibernate application that currently works only on Weblogic 12c, and we're adding the possibility to use it on JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Our persistence.xml is using the property `hibernate.archive.autodetection` set to `class` and the `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` option set to `false`.

This works perfectly on Weblogic, but it's not working on JBoss, I'm getting a "not a managed type" error for every class.

Is there a way that Hibernate autodetection can be made on JBoss AS, or is it impossible?

Comment: Try with WildFly 10. It uses the Hibernate 5, which probably has different way of configuration.

Comment: Also - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).